# How can I track source of app install and conversions in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I have installed Firebase for my app and I would like to track which marketing channel is driving apps open and my in-app conversions (tracked in Firebase already).

- I have tried using utm tracking links that goes to Google Play and iTunes; however I couldn't find any source data in Firebase: all conversions are attributed to "direct"
- I then tried using Dynamic Links in Firebase console to create dynamic links that include campaign tracking parameters. Same result as the utm tracking links I created

Questions:

- Is Firebase recognising utm tracking links by default? Or there has to be additional coding done when implementing Firebase SDK?
- Similarly for dynamic links: I have only created the links via Firebase console but haven't been doing any coding changes within my app. Is there anything I need to do so that my app open and conversions can be attributed to the source I specified in the dynamic link settings?

Thanks!

Raymond